# Will an MD5 hash keep changing as its input grows?

Tags: mysql, md5

Does the value returned by MySQL's MD5 hash function continue to change indefinitely as the string given to it grows indefinitely?

E.g., will these continue to return different values:

```
MD5("A"+"B"+"C")
MD5("A"+"B"+"C"+"D")
MD5("A"+"B"+"C"+"D"+"E")
MD5("A"+"B"+"C"+"D"+"E"+"D")
... and so on until a very long list of values ....
```

At some point, when we are giving the function very long input strings, will the results stop changing, as if the input were being truncated?

I'm asking because I want to use the MD5 function to compare two records with a large set of fields by storing the MD5 hash of these fields.

======== MADE-UP EXAMPLE (YOU DON'T NEED THIS TO ANSWER THE QUESTION BUT IT MIGHT INTEREST YOU: ========

I have a database application that periodically grabs data from an external source and uses it to update a MySQL table.

Let's imagine that in month #1, I do my first download:

```
downloaded data, where the first field is an ID, a key:
    1,"A","B","C"
    2,"A","D","E"
    3,"B","D","E"

I store this
    1,"A","B","C"
    2,"A","D","E"
    3,"B","D","E"
```

Month #2, I get
        1,"A","B","C"
        2,"A","D","X"
        3,"B","D","E"
        4,"B","F","E"

```
Notice that the record with ID 2 has changed.  Record with ID 4 is new.  So I store two new records:
    1,"A","B","C"
    2,"A","D","E"
    3,"B","D","E"
    2,"A","D","X"
    4,"B","F","E"

This way I have a history of *changes* to the data.

I don't want have to compare each field of the incoming data with each field of each of the stored records.
E.g., if I'm comparing incoming record x with exiting record a, I don't want to have to say:
    Add record x to the stored data if there is no record a such that x.ID == a.ID AND x.F1 == a.F1 AND x.F2 == a.F2 AND x.F3 == a.F3 [4 comparisons]

What I want to do is to compute an MD5 hash and store it:
    1,"A","B","C",MD5("A"+"B"+"C")

Let's suppose that it is month #3, and I get a record:
    1,"A","G","C"
What I want to do is compute the MD5 hash of the new fields: MD5("A"+"G"+"C") and compare the resulting hash with the hashes in the stored data.
If it doesn't match, then I add it as a new record.
I.e., Add record x to the stored data if there is no record a such that x.ID == a.ID AND MD5(x.F1 + x.F2 + x.F3) == a.stored_MD5_value [2 comparisons]

My question is "Can I compare the MD5 hash of, say, 50 fields without increasing the likelihood of clashes?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, practically, it should keep changing. Due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if you continue doing that enough, you should eventually get a collision, but it's impractical that you'll reach that point.

Comment: Thank you - that's the answer I wanted to hear.  And the collisions shouldn't be much of a problem since I'll only be comparing records with the same numeric identifiers.  Now I've got to go write my code.  It's great to be able to go to sleep with a problem and to wake up to find the answer waiting!!

Answer (score 1):

The security of the MD5 hash function is severely compromised. A collision attack exists that can find collisions within seconds on a computer with a 2.6Ghz Pentium4 processor (complexity of 2<sup>24</sup>).
Further, there is also a chosen-prefix collision attack that can produce a collision for two chosen arbitrarily different inputs within hours, using off-the-shelf computing hardware (complexity 2<sup>39</sup>).
The ability to find collisions has been greatly aided by the use of off-the-shelf GPUs. On an NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS graphics processor, 16-18 million hashes per second can be computed. An NVIDIA GeForce 8800 Ultra can calculate more than 200 million hashes per second.

These hash and collision attacks have been demonstrated in the public in various situations, including colliding document files and digital certificates.
See http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/On%20Collisions%20for%20MD5%20-%20M.M.J.%20Stevens.pdf

A number of projects have published MD5 rainbow tables online, that can be used to reverse many MD5 hashes into strings that collide with the original input, usually for the purposes of password cracking.

Comment: It's good that you know that and share that knowledge, but please be aware that not all uses of MD5 are concerned with security. Like this one.

Comment: The MD5 attack techniques are rendered ineffective by the use of a sufficiently long salt.

Comment: True again, but the application of MD5 in this question has nothing to do with security. It just never will be attacked, because there's no point to it.

Comment: Mchl is absolutely correct: I'm not using this for security at all, only to make record comparison easier.  Part of the reason that I asked the question at stackoverflow, where I want to ask only high-quality questions, is that searching for answers returned so much stuff about password encryption and not about the algorithm itself.